# Stripe Apple Pay Integration

Tags: python, swift, stripe-payments

## **How do I retrieve the client Secret?**

**a problem that doesn't let me sleep:**

```
extension CheckoutViewController {
  func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: StripeAPI.PaymentMethod, paymentInformation: PKPayment, completion: @escaping     STPIntentClientSecretCompletionBlock) {

 let clientSecret = ... // Retrieve the PaymentIntent client secret from your backend (see Server-side step above)
    // Call the completion block with the client secret or an error
    completion(clientSecret, error);
}


func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCompleteWith status: STPApplePayContext.PaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
      switch status {
    case .success:
        // Payment succeeded, show a receipt view
        break
    case .error:
        // Payment failed, show the error
        break
    case .userCancellation:
        // User canceled the payment
        break
    @unknown default:
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

}

**I get this error: StripeApplePay/PaymentIntent+API.swift:30: Assertion failed: `secret` format does not match expected client secret formatting. So I guess that'S why it doesn't work

I wanted to incorporate Stripe in my Apple Pay. However the Stripe documentation only tells me to retrieve the client data but not how and through which objects. Would be amazing if you could help :*(**

Comment: For anyone who's looking for the stripe docu: https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay

Comment: The client secret is returned as part of the PaymentIntent creation. You ask Stripe for a PaymentIntent for say $10USD and you get a PaymentIntent object back and one of its properties is called `client_secret` and has the value you are looking for. That's what you send back to your client-side code/app

Comment: @koopajah thank you so much! That solved my issue. Sadly, my server broke so off to the next problem xD